# Executing Python Script from C# (ironPython is not an option)

Tags: c#, python

I have a C# Application and I want to run python script by passing some arguments and i also want to return some values from python. should i make a .dll file of my python script ? or is there any other way.

I can't use ironpython because i am unable to import my python project libraries in ironpython

thanks

Comment: Can't you just execute the command lines through the console via c#?  Like so: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469764/run-command-prompt-commands

Answer (score 1):

Convert your Python script to executable using `py2exe.exe`, and call it from C# using `Process`.

Another way is to execute cmd command "python program.py" from your C# program. But, you've to make sure that environment variable for Python is set.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [`Process`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). This will let you set the arguments. If possible, have the script write to `STDOUT` and capture that output with your `Process` object. There are plenty of tutorials on how to do this.

There's no good way to "return" a value from another process without capturing the output stream, especially considering that you're working with two different languages here.